# Are these $f_n$ equicontinuous?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, continuity

Let $f_n$ be a sequence of real-valued functions defined on $\mathbb{R}$ satisfying

1. $f_n \to f$ uniformly in the compact subsets of $\mathbb{R}$
2. $f_n^{-1}$ is bi-Lipschitz
3. $1 \leq (f_n^{-1})'(x) \leq C_n$
4. $\frac{1}{C_n} \leq f'_n(x) \leq 1$

Is there any chance that $f_n$ are equicontinuous on $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: see the Examples section of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equicontinuity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, and the assumption $|f_n'|\le 1$ is alone enough to establish that. By the mean value theorem, continuity holds with $\delta = \epsilon$; this choice of $\delta$ works for all functions at all points.