# Please verify my work about an equicontinuous sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, continuity

Please check this work below. It is self-explanatory. I am unsure because I use a sequence composed with another sequence with the same index ($f_n^{-1}(u_n)$).

> We have a sequence of functions $f_n:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$.
> Now, since $|f_n'| \leq 1$, it follows that $f_n$ are uniformly equicontinuous.
>
> Therefore, for fixed $\epsilon$, there is a $\delta$ (depends only on $\epsilon$) such that
> $$\text{if $|y-z| < \delta$, then $|f_n(y) - f_n(z)|  < \epsilon$}.$$
> for any $n$.
> Let $u_n \in L^2(0,T)$. If we look at the contrapositive of the above statement, we must have that in the set
> $$\{|{u}_n(t+h) - u_n(t)| > \epsilon\} = \{|f_n(f_n^{-1}({u}_n(t+h))) - f_n(f_n^{-1}( u_n(t)))| > \epsilon\},$$
> we must have
> $$|f_n(\tilde u_n(t+h)) - f_n({u}_n(t))| \geq \delta.$$

Is it correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have to assume $f_n$ are invertible in order to talk about $f_n^{-1}$. Second, the correct conclusion, following the steps of your argument, is
$$|f_n^{-1}(  u_n(t+h)) - f_n^{-1}({u}_n(t))| \geq \delta$$

The equicontinuity of $f_n$ can never get you a **lower** bound on the difference of $f_n$ at two different points. After all, constant functions are equicontinuous.  Nothing in the stated assumptions excludes the possibility $f_n\equiv 0$.

If you want to conclude with 
$$|f_n(  u_n(t+h)) - f_n({u}_n(t))| \geq \delta$$
you need equicontinuity of $f_n^{-1}$. Which you will get by using the assumptions in [your earlier question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/775861).

Comment: Sorry that was a typo in my OP. It is meant to be the correct conclusion you quoted. Thanks for the check!